# Shorter ways of saying "Keep doing what you're doing or keep doing similar stuffs to what you're doing"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Person 1: Keep acting like a crazy person by moving randomly and
> erractically.
>
> Person 2: Like this?
>
> Person 1: Carry on like this.

Is "carry on like this" the right way to say it, and can I shorten it to "carry on"? I am guessing so, but I am just trying to make 100% sure it makes perfect sense in that context.

Comment: It does not sound particularly idiomatic in American English except perhaps in a military context. “Yes. Keep on doing that” sounds more natural to me  (but perhaps not to a speaker of British English.)  Notice the contrast between “this” and “that” between the two speakers.

Comment: Yes. "Keep on doing that" is common in British English too. So is "Keep doing that."

Comment: As @JeffMorrow says, person 1's response doesn't seem natural. I'd expect "yes, like that" or something similar. In other contexts "carry on" could be fine.

Comment: "Carry on like this" would mean "Do what I'm doing". If the person is being asked to keep on doing what _they_ are doing, it should be "Carry on like that" (or just "Carry on".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keep it up!**

[Cambridge *keep it up*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep-it-up)
used to encourage someone to continue doing something:
*You're doing very well everybody. Keep it up!*

[Wiktionary *keep it up*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_it_up)
1(idiomatic) To maintain or continue a positive streak.

(It can also be used in a sarcastic, threatening way, too.)

Comment: I agree and would add another:  "keep up the good work."